# is visual-studio 2013 support Programming for Windows-mobile or Windows-CE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile

is visual-studio 2013 support Programming for Windows-mobile or Windows-CE ?

Until now I Programming on Visual-studio 2008 and I plan to migrate to 2013.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Technically.

Visual Studio 2008 is the last version to support Windows Mobile, the last Windows Mobile SDK, for Windows Mobile 6.5.3, supports at most Visual Studio 2008.

Windows CE, however, is different (note that we're talking about CE devices that are *not* running Windows Mobile nor Windows Phone 7). The most recent version of CE is now called "Windows Embedded Compact 2013" and drops the "CE" moniker, however this platform is supported by both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: thanks for the help, i can't find in visual-studio 2013 the Windows Embedded Compact for start work with , where to find it ?

Comment: @user4268796 check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197932.aspx you need to have the Windows Embedded Compact SDK installed first, and you typically get the SDK from your hardware provider.